# Capture string from URL

Tags: java

Can anyone suggest me in java is it possible to capture Name from below URL.

http://www.example.in/Ramesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the URL and take the name like this.

```
String url = "http://www.example.in/Ramesh";
String[] name = url.split(".in/");
System.out.println(name[1]);
```

Output - `Ramesh`

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.in/Ramesh");
System.out.println(url.getPath().substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try{


    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.in/Ramesh");
    String[] words = (url.toString()).split("[/.:]+");

    for (String word : words){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```